# How can I check if user is connected in order to display phone number Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have a little problem which I can't find a convenient solution to it. I have a button in the user profile page which on click will display the user phone number which was initially hidden. It is working quite alright but what I want is that, in order for the phone number to be revealed, the user must be signed in if not it will redirect the user to the login page with a flash message saying "You must be logged in, in order to view this number"

In my Profile Details View file I have this

```
<span class="job-is ft"  id="more" onclick="$('.details').slideToggle(function(){$('#more').html($('.details').is(':visible')?'Cacher le numero':'Voir le numero');});">Voir le numero</span>

<div class="extra-job-info details" style="display:none">
    <p style="text-align: center; padding: 10px; font-size: 45px;">
       <i class="la la-phone"></i> {{ $profiledetail->phone }}
    </p>
</div>
```

In my user Controller I have this

```
public function jobberDetails($id) {
    $profiledetail = User::find($id);

    return view('Users.profileDetail', compact('profiledetail'));
}
```

My web file

```
// Route qui permet d'afficher,le profil d'un Jobbeur
 Route::get('/jobber/profiledetails/{id}','UserController@jobberDetails')->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'))->name('profileDetails');
```

In my login view

```
@section('content')

<section>
        <div class="block remove-bottom">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">

                    @include('Flash/flash')

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        @if (session('confirmation-success'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                {{ session('confirmation-success') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        @if (session('confirmation-danger'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {!! session('confirmation-danger') !!}
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="account-popup-area signin-popup-box static">
                            <div class="account-popup">
                                <span>Connexion</span>
                                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                                     {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    <div class="cfield{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus />
                                        <i class="la la-user"></i>

                                         @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                            <span class="help-block" style="float: left;">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="cfield{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <input type="password" placeholder="********"  name="password" required />
                                        <i class="la la-key"></i>

                                         @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                            <span class="help-block" style="float: left;">
                                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                            </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="remember-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}><label for="cb1">Remember me</label>
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="#" title="">Forgot Password?</a>
                                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                                </form>
                                <div class="extra-login">
                                    <span>Or</span>
                                    <div class="login-social">
                                        <a class="fb-login" href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                        <a class="tw-login" href="#" title=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- LOGIN POPUP -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 @endsection
```

Comment: You need to check for `Auth::user()` if it is logged in reveal the number.

Comment: i did that already and its working. but what i want is that it should redirect to login page with a flash message

Comment: As it is right now. You don't want compact the user phone number with the returned view. When _Voir le numero_ is clicked, you want to make a request to an endpoint to retrieve the number. That way you can set up a middleware on that endpoint to only proceed to the return  the number when the guest is logged in.

Comment: So to get the only the phone number do I have to do this $phone = User::find($id)->phone->get();  ??